# How to get a continuous ColumnChart?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I'm using a `ColumnChart` to represent the elevation in a map, as suggested by Google.
However, the columns are separated by spaces, and that renders ugly white spaces between the
columns, like in Google's own example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths

Is there a way to tell the column chart to make columns that fill up the whole space? I would like something like this:

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4I8oi3WqY5o/UIZnzbXql_I/AAAAAAAAAcE/GO4wl6I2-lM/s1600/Charts.png

I suspect that the only way is with lots of points.

My code:

```
var option = {
  legend: 'none',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  colors: ["#C9CFF5"],
  titleColor: '#C9CFF5',
  focusBorderColor: '#00AA00',
  titleY: 'Elevation (m)',
  bar: { groupWidth: '100%' }
}
// Build data
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation (m):');
for (var i = 0; i < trackmarks.length; i++) {
  data.addRow(['', trackaltis[i]]);
}

// Draw the chart using the data within its DIV.
chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));
chart.draw(data, option);
```

My code is pretty standard: same as Google's, same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify option:

```
bar: {groupWidth: "100%"}
```

bar.groupWidth: *Percentage of the available width for each group (e.g. '20%'), where '100%' means that groups have no space between them*

**Update:** That example uses [old version of column charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart_old) which loads package `columnchart`

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["columnchart"]});
```

The latest code for column chart is loaded using `corechart`:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

Change that and example should work as expected without spaces.

Comment: Yep, I had that already. No effect, completely ignored. Don't know why... Added my code for reference.

Comment: Strange, I didn't try it with your example before.

Comment: It seems that it depends on width of browser window. Sometimes I get chart without spaces and if I change the width (increase/decrease) I get spaces.

Comment: I think that depends on the density of columns, not really on window width. Try a chart with very few columns to avoid 'overpopulation'.

Comment: The corechart renders even worse: only shows half of the chart (?), and still with spaces.

Comment: BTW, still with spaces in firefox, but not in chrome.

Comment: Cannot reproduce problem with latest Firefox or IE10. See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hafug/1/edit).

Comment: It looks fine. But in Dolphin in Android it shows the vertical bars, that actually flicker as you resize the window. My chart has a fix width, while your example says '100%'... So probably a browser rendering problem. But even at 100%, it does not show the whole graph. Now, something interesting: the `tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },` works with corechart, but not with columnchart.

Comment: Ok, so tired about the rendering problems, I gave up and went with a `LineChart` and `corechart`. Looks much better and allow more fine tuned results. Thanks anyway Anto!