# How to prevent popup in ColumnChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, balloon

I use a google maps ColumnChart to reprensent the elevation in a map.
I also use a mouseover to print info and show the correspondent position.
When a column in the chart is clicked, it popups an info balloon, like here:

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4I8oi3WqY5o/UIZnzbXql_I/AAAAAAAAAcE/GO4wl6I2-lM/s1600/Charts.png

This balloon is ok for desktops, but a pain for mobile (very hard to close, etc).

How can I completely disable it? It has to do with the second data column passed to the chart.
No balloons!

Thanks!

L.

**EDIT**
Code added by request:

```
var option = {
  legend: 'none',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  colors: ["#C9CFF5"],
  titleColor: '#C9CFF5',
  focusBorderColor: '#00AA00',
  titleY: 'Elevation (m)',
  tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
  bar: { groupWidth: '100%' }
}
// Build data
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation (m):');
for (var i = 0; i < trackmarks.length; i++) {
  data.addRow(['', trackaltis[i]]);
}

// Draw the chart using the data within its DIV.
chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));
chart.draw(data, option);
```

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle to accompany the question?  It's difficult to answer without any code reference.

Comment: Set the `tooltip.trigger` option to `'none'` to disable the tooltips.

Comment: @asgallant: Yep, the first thing I tried was `tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },` but it does not work.

Comment: @lando: Sorry, you're right. But my code is pretty standard, so nothing interesting. And the question is actually code-independent: how to get rid of the `ColumnChart` tooltip. Anyway, relevant code is added. Thanks.

Comment: @asgallant: Actually, the `tooltip: { trigger: 'none' }`, works with `corechart`, but not with `columnchart`. I dont want to use `corechart` since it has other rendering problems, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596202/how-to-get-a-continuous-columnchart/22596925?noredirect=1#comment34413340_22596925

Comment: The `columnchart` package is deprecated, and does not support most of the feature set released in the past 4 years or so, including the `tooltip` options.

Comment: @asgallant: Yes, I know. But it has a nasty bug that `columnchart` does not have:  it does not render the whole chart, but only part of it.

Comment: @asgallant: Tired about `columnchart`, I tried `linechart` with `corechart`. Found another bug....